# sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) error in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

When I execute the following code:

```
'driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h5[text()='Users and Groups Management']")).click();'
```

I get the following error

```
Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//h5[text()='Users and Groups Management']}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:323)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:428)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:353)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:315)
    at Basic.main(Basic.java:23)
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

The page contains the following lines and I have also tried waiting an appropriate amount of time to execute and also new `WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//h5[text()='Users and Groups Management']")).click();`
Nothing worked!

```
<div _ngcontent-ncj-c134="" class="card-header flex-centrally-aligned border-0"><h5 _ngcontent-ncj-c134="" class="text-center font-weight-bold m-0"> Users and Groups Management </h5></div>
<h5 _ngcontent-ncj-c134="" class="text-center font-weight-bold m-0"> Users and Groups Management </h5>
```

Please share your thoughts on how I can proceed on this. Thanks!

Comment: The stack trace does not appear to have an error message. Either that or this error message is just poorly worded. Are you sure you included the full error message and stack trace in your question?

Comment: Is your driver null or not? It's look like you are trying to call a null ojbect.